# Media Source Extension with Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, media-source

My application receives a RTP Stream (H264 or VP8), put it into Fragmented MP4 or WebM and send it over Websocket to my Javascript App where I display video using Media Source Extension.
Chrome works ok with both Codecs but Firefox shows a huge CPU usage, 50%-60%. 
Chrome only 6%.

Javascript calls mediaSource.updateBuffer, wait for updateend and then call again mediaSource.updateBuffer. Nothing different as any example out there.

Anyone having also this problem with Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot more specific information (profiling your code, checking your browser flags and capabilities) it isn't possible to definitively say what the issue is.

I suspect that in Chrome, your codecs are hardware accelerated, and in Firefox they are not.

Comment: not sure about that because Firefox only uses 15% with WebRTC. I run some more tests if I do not call play() in the video element the CPU remains low. I do not know exactly what triggers the video decoding process.

Comment: @Sergio It's apples and bananas.  Video with WebRTC is encoded in a way that optimizes for latency over quality.  The resulting video is fast to encode *and* decode.  Besides, there's no guarantee that Firefox wouldn't use hardware accelerated codecs for WebRTC, and software codecs for playback of other video.

Comment: apples and bananas...not very good example. As I wrote, I am only decoding, no encoding in Javascript. Encoding is done in my c++ application where i use the libvpx library and my app only uses 4% of the CPU for encoding. You tell me that Firefox needs 50% to decode a single VP8 stream...?? They are really optimizing the decoding process...and the fact that Chrome only needs 5-6% close to my app tells me that something is not ok with Firefox...

Comment: @Sergio Who knows, as I said, there's not nearly enough information in your question to determine this.  You could open up the profiler in your developer tools and help narrow this down, and I could help you further after that.  On some machines, it can definitely take a lot of CPU to decode a single stream.  On others, no.  I don't know anything about what you're running.